# Input allow only 6 digits and after comma seperated and allow another 6 digits in angular js

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs

Hi i am new to angularjs we want to implement a input text box which will allow only six digits and after entering six digits a comma separated will add and enter another six digits . Can you please help me. The sample code we have now is

```
**html** 

 <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<input type="text" ng-model="number" required="required" numbers- 
 only="numbers-only" />
</div>
```

Angular js controller

```
   angular.module('myApp', []).directive('numbersOnly', function(){
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
     link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
      modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (inputValue) {

       if (inputValue == undefined) return '' 
       var transformedInput = inputValue.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''); 
       if (transformedInput!=inputValue) {
          modelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
          modelCtrl.$render();
       }         

       return transformedInput;         
       });
    }
 };
  });

 function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.number = ''
   }
```

fiddler link we found

http://jsfiddle.net/thomporter/DwKZh/

Comment: What's the problem with this code?

Answer (score 2):

have a look at [ui-mask](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/#/mask), set the mask as `999999-999999` or you can also use [angular-input-mask](http://assisrafael.github.io/angular-input-masks/)

Answer (score 0):

Edit your angular directive and bind a key press event to the textbox element. Inside the event check length. If length is 6 add a comma and rebind new value to your text box.

Answer (score 0):

All you got to do is attach a key press event inside the directive `link` and check for input length and act accordingly. Instead of modifying your code, I pretty much wrote my own. Here is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mrezxzzj/3/)

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="number" number-only required="required" />
</div>
```

Here is the modified directive code:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

}])

app.directive('numberOnly', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

      // Attach key press event

      elem.bind('keypress', function(e) {

        // Check if its a number 

        if (e.which >= 48 && e.which <= 57) {



            var ar = scope.number.split(',');

            if (ar[ar.length - 1].length >= 6) {
              scope.number = scope.number + ',';
            }

            scope.$apply();


        }
        else {
          e.preventDefault();
        }
      });

    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Hey thanks jade, for u r code but we are unable to delete values what we enter in input in Firefox browser like when we enter backspace or delete its not working its working fine in chrome